# How to change columnheader font

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to create a student information system as you can see in the picture.
The ListView's header and item fonts are the same. I want to change the header font, but when I change the header the items are also changing.

[image: clicktosee]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for VB.NET.

Set the `OwnerDraw`-property of the `ListView` to `True` and then use following code:

```vb
Private Sub ListView1_DrawColumnHeader(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawColumnHeader
    Dim strFormat As New StringFormat()

    If e.Header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center Then
        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    ElseIf e.Header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right Then
        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    End If

    e.DrawBackground()
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.SteelBlue, e.Bounds)
    Dim headerFont As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont, Brushes.White, e.Bounds, strFormat)
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawItem
    e.DrawDefault = True
End Sub
```

Source: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c5e9191-07f7-4b61-9bc5-fea739f99385/how-do-i-change-the-column-header-colour-in-a-listview-in-vbnet?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 0):

We should add this code to Work :

```
Private Sub Frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        ListView1.OwnerDraw = True
End Sub
```